# PHP CURL Error - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, curl

basically, this error only occurs in CURL

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

But when I visit it directly the link directly on my browser, it works!

What are your recommendations on fixing this one or the cause of this error?

Note: the server is coded in ASP and it only occurs on one API Call

Comment: yeah on the console, that is also the error, there is no header/options on the curl request. and also there is no cookie involve..

Comment: I am guessing that this is a Server Error, but I do not know what part or section of the Server this occurs

Comment: are you getting any errors in your webserver log? Is the server running on the same machine, where the curl commando is executed? If so try to add the called domain to map to localhost in your hosts file...

Comment: I solved this by requesting via POST instead of GET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember facing the same issue a long time back.  While I don't remember what exactly sorted out the issue, I remember trying the following:

1. I was trying to pass the query parameters in the URL directly and I tried passing through POST method
2. I tried using a proxy with curl to see if I was possibly being blocked by the other server
3. I believe I also asked my host to look into it and they made some Apache setting changes

Comment: Do you remember what the result was?

Comment: I think the host did change some Apache settings but not sure what settings they were. Immediately after changing the settings, it started working. Also there might have been an issue with the way I was sending the parameters in my curl request.

Comment: I also here that litespeed anti ddos measures might be placing a temp ban on the calling IP. I believe this is what happened to me. We are still in discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by removing **whitespace characters** from the URL. In my situation, it was the proxy server that was erroring out, not the web server.

In PHP:

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
```

Comment: If the whitespace characters are a valid part of the URL, you could use the rawurlencode() function instead, to replace whitespace characters with %20

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with this code:

```
        $url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 44455); //Set the port to connect to
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 44455); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        echo $xml = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

Got it solved by disabling this:

```
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 44455);
```