# PHP / CURL / ASP.NET / C# - Send files bigger than 9mb

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, curl, file-upload

I want to send a file from PHP (v5.4) via CURL to an ASP.NET WebApi (C#). I thought this should be easy but I'm facing some strange behaviour I can't explain:

**php  script:**

```
<?php   
    $files = array();
    $files['file_content'] = '@'.realpath('./myfile.jpg');

    $url = 'https://localhost:44307/api/v1/File';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // ignore ssl verifyer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);

    echo 'ErrorMsg: '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
    echo "ErrorNr.:".curl_errno($ch).'<br>';    

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**php.ini:**

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 20
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```

**Web.config:**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800" maxRequestLength="2097152" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" /> 
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>        
</system.webServer>
```

When I execute the script with an file bigger than 9mb (also with e.g. two 5mb-files) I get the following result after a few minutes depending on the size of the file:

```
ErrorMsg: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
ErrorNr.:56
```

When I change to an file of 9mb or less everything works fine.

Also: I get the same error when calling CURL from cmd (Windows 7):

```
curl --form upload=@myfile.jpg --form press=OK https://localhost:44303/api/v1/File -k -sslv3
```

=> Everything happens on my local machine, so no firewall and no vpn.

I have tried multiple combinations of parameters but I don't make any progress. Actually it is more guessing than real testing. Maybe there is just one little thing I overlooked all the time?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After guessing for almost one day I had the idea of just publishing the asp.net part to an Azure Website as it might be a problem of my local configuration.

As I published it, I had to remove this line of my php curl configuration:

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

With the Azure Website I can now upload bigger files - just as it should be.

I tried to understand why it is working on Azure but not on localhost - but actually I did not found the answer yet. Looks like some configuration problem of the IIS express and Visual Studio 2013. Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the problem itself, but the error message is apparently 'Connection reset by peer'.

```
See also:
```

- [PHP CURL Error - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500847/php-curl-error-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer)
- [CURL ERROR: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)
- [docker Mule-server curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543787/docker-mule-server-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions but nothing worked for me. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction of uploading only 9MB can be caused by using the secure **https** URL instead of the non secure **http** URL.

So in the php script you should change the line 5 into:

```
    $url = 'http://localhost:44307/api/v1/File';
```

The appropriate curl command would be:

```
    curl --form upload=@myfile.jpg --form press=OK http://localhost:44303/api/v1/File -k -sslv3
```

When using the secure URL, the upload stops actually in less than ten seconds, as can be seen in the curl progress meter. The connection is closed a couple of minutes after this, giving the false appearance that the actual problem would be in the server (The error code 56 indicates that the connection was reset by peer).